# Navigate to GoogleMap and MapKit in Flutter without Dev Dependency

Tags: flutter, dart

How to Navigate Latitude & Longitude to GoogleMap and MapKit in Flutter without using Dependency.

Am using Dependency this Dependency - **url_launcher: ^6.1.4**

```
 static Future<void> openMap(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    String iosUrl = 'https://maps.apple.com/?q=$latitude,$longitude';
    if (GetPlatform.isAndroid) {
      String googleUrl ='https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude';
      if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
        await launch(googleUrl);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $googleUrl';
      }
    }else{
      if (await canLaunch(iosUrl)) {
        await launch(iosUrl);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not open the map.';
      }
    }
  }
```

This above code is Working Fine and Running properly. But I need Solution without Dependency

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to navigate to google map without `url_launcher` plugin you can launch google map without `url_launch` package, you can use [intent 1.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/intent) package, this will work only on android platform.

```
import 'package:intent/intent.dart' as android_intent;

 android_intent.Intent()
      ..setAction(android_action.Action.ACTION_VIEW)
      ..setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=$latitude,$longitude"))
      ..setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
      ..startActivity().catchError((error) => print(error));
```

Comment: I Need for Both android and Ios

Comment: try this package https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher

Comment: I need help or suggestion without using Dependency because i have already done using dependency but client requirement is no use of dependency

Comment: this external_app_launcher: ^3.1.0 A Flutter plugin which helps you to open another app from your app. The package asks you for four parameters out of which two are mandatory. please read documentation this is not  url_launcher: ^6.1.4 which you have used